# Python Azure Runbooks - Selenium Issues

Tags: python, azure, selenium-webdriver

Hoping I’ve come to the right spot, I’ve been researching online for the last week and still stuck. Please see below. I’m new to azure (couple of months) and a one person team.

Context - I have an azure subscription account setup which includes a resource group, sql server and database, storage account and automation account with some runbooks. I’m looking to execute some .py files which use selenium.

Issue - I have a .py (Python) file in my blob storage account that uses selenium webdriver to login to a website and screen scape information. I have been running this on my local pc and now looking to fully automate in azure.

I tested that i can access the website with my Python runbook. I then uploaded selenium chrome driver into my Python packages in automation account and added logic to utilize the chrome driver and execute my .py file. I keep getting an error “[WinError 10050] A socket operation encountered a dead network”.

Does anyone know if you can execute a Python runbook that calls a .py file with selenium? Do I need to also install chrome into my Python packages (if that’s an option)? I saw some stuff about headless but haven’t tested that yet, want to make sure I’m not going down the wrong path.

My client doesn’t have server or virtual machine I can set this up on hence using azure.

Thank you in advance

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to execute a Python runbook that invokes a `.py` file with Selenium in Azure Automation.

If you want to reference the shared resources such as credentials, variables, connections, and certificates, you can use [Azure Automation Python emulated assets module](https://github.com/WenJason/python_emulated_assets) as detailed in the given GitHub.

Add the python packages in azure automation as shown:

*Path: Automation account -> Python packages -> Add a Python package*

[image]

*Note:* To manage Azure resources, use the Run As account credential from your Automation account. To work with Azure VMs, you can use the Azure Compute client for Python.

*Looking into the error,*

> “[WinError 10050] A socket operation encountered a dead network”.

Selenium usually depends on various components, specifically the Chrome browser and the Chrome WebDriver. Verify that you have the correct versions of Chrome browser and Chrome WebDriver installed and compatible with each other.

You can get the appropriate version of the Chrome WebDriver binary from the [site](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

Once you checked all the above, add the chrome web driver in the Python environment and run/upload your code in azure automation runbook.